# Spring security REST not handling login request (404)

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-security

I've tried to follow [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security) and I'm stuck. My request to

```
POST http://localhost:8080/MyWebsite_Membership/api/login
```

returns a 404 every time. In the debug log I can see

```
WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for POST /MyWebsite_Membership/api/login
```

I can't seem to figure out why my config isn't registering some kind of handler for that URI when all the documents/tutorials seem to indicate that Spring will automatically handle that URI by default.

Security config

```xml
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" >

        <intercept-url pattern="/api/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <csrf disabled="true" />
        <form-login
                authentication-success-handler-ref="restAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="restAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        />
        <logout />
    </http>
    <beans:bean id="restAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.mywebsite.membership.web.RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <beans:bean id="restAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="com.mywebsite.membership.web.RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
    <beans:bean id="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.mywebsite.membership.web.RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <!-- Password is prefixed with {noop} to indicate to DelegatingPasswordEncoder that
                NoOpPasswordEncoder should be used. This is not safe for production, but makes reading
                in samples easier. Normally passwords should be hashed using BCrypt -->
                <user name="jimi" password="{noop}jimispassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="bob" password="{noop}bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `/MyWebsite_Membership/api/login` which is not mapped to any resource.  Use `/MyWebsite_Membership/login` instead.

Comment: That in itself didn't work, but it helped me get to what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Security there will be default authentication processing filter `<form-login>`(In XML Config) `.formLogin()` (In Java Config) whose default configuration is

**Defaults in xml configuration (You can customize if you want)**

```xml
login-page="/login"
default-target-url="/" <!-- On Successful athentication -->
authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
username-parameter="username" <!-- For custom login page if it has different param name - say email -->
password-parameter="password" <!-- For custom login page custom parameter -->
```

**Defaults in java configuration (You can customize if you want)**

```java
.loginPage("/login")
.defaultSuccessUrl("/") //On Authentication success
.failureUrl("/login?error") //On Authentication failure
.usernameParameter("username") //Default auth param1
.passwordParameter("password") //Default auth param2
```

**In Your code** 
As you have not mentioned `login-page` in your configuration

it will provide default login page on `GET: /login`
And default Authentication processing URL `POST: /login`
(params should be `username` and `password`)

So use

```
POST - http://localhost:8080/MyWebsite_Membership/login
```

For authentication from your postman or any rest client. It will not show 404
No code changes are required.

**In OP's case springSecurityFilterChain configured for url pattern**

```xml
<url-pattern>/api/**</url-pattern>
```

If springSecurityFilterChain(DelegatingFilterProxy) is configured for url pattern `/api/**`, spring security defaults `/login` and `/logout` won't work then you need to configure below URL's to pass through springSecurityFilterChain.

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/**</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/logout</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Or you can configure as explained by OP in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

What finally did it for me was understanding that this code isn't handled inside the context of the servlet, so none of the paths are prepended with /api/.

1. Make sure the web.xml mapping is correct. A filter-mapping of /api/* will not catch the /login request.
2. Add login-processing-url="/api/login" to override the default "/login"

Comment: **A filter-mapping of /api/* will not catch the /login request.** Other alternative is to use `<filter-mapping>` with multiple `<url-pattern>` entries. Even adding `<url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>` also works in your case.